# Weighted Interval Scheduling with dependent jobs/job with multiple required running time

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, memoization, knapsack-problem

Interval scheduling algorithms are pretty much based around sorting jobs by end time, but what if scheduling job A means you must schedule job C.

For instance, say you are trying to schedule radio programs and program A runs Monday 10am-11am and 2pm-3pm, but program B runs Monday 1:30-2:30?  You can't run only the 10-11 portion of program A. It's all or nothing.  Alternatively, say the program runs Mon, Wed, Fri but at different times each day.

Ideas I've played around with:

Shortest path algorithm where you simultaneously traverse 7 graphs for each day of the week, each graph sorted to connect only programs coming after.  If you choose program A on monday, you choose it on all days, as so on.  This solution doesn't solve the issue if the program needs to run twice in one day.

Generating an n by n matrix for the n programs and checking each's compatibility with the others.  Traverse a graph where each program only connects with non-conflicting programs.  A bit stuck on this idea and looking for next steps or new ideas entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just re-asked this question on [CS Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124884/86589) since this one is old and the equivalencies in the accepted answer are a bit tenuous. Re-posting my answer here for higher visibility:

This is equivalent to the maximum weighted independent set problem - given a graph with weighted vertices, find a subset of the vertices such that no two vertices in the subset are adjacent in the graph and the sum of their weights is maximized.

The graph the problem is being solved on is a type of interval graph where each vertex represents a group of dependent intervals and its weight is the sum of the intervals' weights. An edge is drawn between two vertices if one or more of their intervals overlap.

I haven't determined if this formulation is tractable or not. While the problem is NP-hard, we know it can be solved efficiently for certain types of graphs, including interval graphs where each vertex represents a single interval. See the [Independent Set Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) for known algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb for scheduling is that almost everything is NP-complete except a few special cases. Suppose you could find a schedule that filled up every hour in the day, given possible programs that required an arbitrary number of disconnected time-slots. Then you could solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover - the elements of X are time-slots, and the subsets S are programs. An exact cover corresponds to scheduling programs that fill every time-slot without overlapping each other.

I think this means you are looking for heuristics, such as Late Acceptance Hill-Climbing (http://www.yuribykov.com/LAHC/), limited discrepancy search (http://wiki.cs.pdx.edu/cs543-spring2010/important_algorithms.html), and ordinary hill-climbing from multiple random starts. I suggest that, whatever else you do, you conclude with a hill-climb designed to spot small improvements that people can spot, to make sure your computer doesn't produce a schedule that people can make obvious improvements to.